How does Turkey have higher labour productivity than Portugal and Romania but lower GDP per capita PPP?
I avoided using nominal GDP per Capita because of Lira devaluation.
Here is the labour productivity of Turkey, Portugal, Romania and some other countries (2022)
https://data.oecd.org/lprdty/gdp-per-hour-worked.htm
Expressed in 2010 Constant US Dollars
Turkey - $52.52
Portugal - $43.10
Slovenia - $46.51
Romania - $35.89
Mexico - $19.28
Spain - $53.10
Italy - $54.2
Now you look at GDP per Capita in PPP (2022)
https://www.imf.org/external/datamapper/PPPPC@WEO/TUR/SVN/ROU/PRT/MEX/ESP/ITA
Turkey - $39,280
Portugal - $42,700
Slovenia - $48,710
Romania - $43,180
Mexico - $23,560
Spain - $47,670
Italy - $52,560

Mexico is what I expected it to be, it is almost half the productivity of the other countries and has almost half the GDP per Capita PPP.
Turkey on the other hand has labour productivity similar to Spain and Italy and is yet nowhere near their GDP per Capita PPP.
Romanian productivity is at $35/hour yet manages to have a higher GDP per Capita PPP than Turkey with 52/hour.

Can someone explain this?
I just measured labour productivity for 2023, from labour productivity growth stats. Turkey is going to surpass Italy and Spain when it comes to labour productivity. So why is Turkey much poorer than Spain and Italy?
https://www.ceicdata.com/en/indicator/turkey/labour-productivity-growth#:~:text=What%20was%20Turkey's%20Labour%20Productivity,table%20below%20for%20more%20data.

Romania exhibits the same behavior.

Yes, I don't understand why there is such a massive gap between labour productivity and income levels. Turkey's Gini Index is similar to Mexico and the USA, it's not as bad as South Africa or Russia. So I'm left guessing..

this could be explained by different dependency ratios did you looked at that? I am guessing female labor force participation in Turkey is also probably lower so that’s another possible explanation

Yeah, you could be right.
https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SL.TLF.TOTL.FE.ZS?locations=TR-RO-PT

I think it is also because of a high unemployment rate. Labor productivity can be the same, but since there are a lot of non-working persons, the slice is smaller for everyone. (As the data show: https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SL.UEM.TOTL.NE.ZS?end=2022&locations=TR-RO-PT-IT&start=2022&view=bar)

It could be that Turkey has

a lower capital stock, and/or
a lower ratio of fixed capital formation to GDP

than Italy or Romania.

Why is this not reflected in labor productivity, which measures total output (created with labor and capital) devided by worked hours?

When computing labour productivity, the OECD divides GDP by a labour input, where "Labour input is defined as total hours worked of all persons engaged in production". Only the workforce is taken into account.
When computing GDP per capita, the total population is taken into account.
For this reason, countries with higher unemployment, lower participation rate (especially for women), with an older population, or a larger shadow economy have - ceteris paribus, ie. for a same level of labour productivity- on average a lower GDP/capita.
